# Merge Two df with different number of columns with R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes, they have an overlapping set of columns but some unique columns too.

They also contain some of the same observations.

To give a concrete example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
               age = c(1:4), 
               party = c(3:6)
)    


df2 <- data.frame(Name = c("a", "e", "c", "f"), 
              other = c(10:13), 
              party = c(3:6)
)
```

Both dfs contain the observations for `a` and `c`

How would I merge the dfs to create a new df that contains all the columns, but does not repeat observations?

Comment: Thanks for showing that this question already has an answer. One thing to consider is that many answers to this question assume some level of familiarity with database or sql-like vocabulary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge()` from base R.

```
merge(df1, df2, all=T)
# Name party age other
# 1    a     3   1    10
# 2    b     4   2    NA
# 3    c     5   3    12
# 4    d     6   4    NA
# 5    e     4  NA    11
# 6    f     6  NA    13
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `full_join` from `dplyr` for that:

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(df1, df2)
```

Which gives you:

```
  Name age party other
1    a   1     3    10
2    b   2     4    NA
3    c   3     5    12
4    d   4     6    NA
5    e  NA     4    11
6    f  NA     6    13
```

Hope that helps!